# Can't get zoom to work in webView in Android Studio

Tags: android, webview, zooming

I am trying to get the zoom to work in my webView in my Android Studio app to no avail.  When I try to zoom it just expands a little bit to the boundaries of the screen.  The zoom feature works if I process my web page in the Chrome browser directly however.  Below is my code.

```
    webView.setInitialScale(270);
    webView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    url = extras.getString("url");

     webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Here is my layout.

```
    <WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="495sp"
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></WebView>
```

The fact that it works in the Chrome browser but not in my app has me perplexed.   I changed the initialscale value to 100 and the view appeared very small but it did allow me to zoom it out to the limits of the screen width.  However, if I set the initialscale value to 270 it makes the webView fill the screen boundaries the way I want.  It just will not let me zoom beyond the physical boundaries of the screen like it does in Chrome.  Anyone have any suggestions on how to zoom beyond the boundaries of the screen?

Comment: Is your webview inside a scrollView? The height value should be in `dp` not `sp`

Comment: I don't think my webview is inside a scrollview, at least I never set it up that way.  All I have is a webview and 3 textviews below the webview in my layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding This Properties

```
/*--WebView--*/
  @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
   private void callWebView(String url) {

     webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webView.getSettings().setScrollBarStyle(View.VISIBLE);
     webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
     webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
     webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
     webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
     webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
     webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());          
     webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);     
     webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
     webView.setScrollBarSize(20);
     webView.loadUrl(url);

  }
```

Comment: I made your changes but the zoom is still limited to the original display.  It seems like there is hard border that just limits my zoom.